# Trouble switching between Pokemon Go accounts on samsung galaxy s7

Tags: pokemon-go, android

Im trying to sign into a different account on my phone but when i click on google account it automatically connects to the account tied to my primary email address. Does anyone know how I can prevent pokemon go from automatically signing in to a certain account?

Comment: try signing out twice in a row

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to be able to log in to another google account you should add the account to the phone itself. This should be somewhere in Settings and then Accounts and then add Google account. After you added it to the phone you will get to choose between the 2 when pressing the google login option of Pokemon Go.